# XAMPP is not working on Mac with macOS Big Sur

Tags: xampp, macos-big-sur

Today, I upgraded my macOS to the latest Big Sur 11.0.1.
After upgrading the OS, I found that the local server XAMPP is not working!
I have all my working projects inside the XAMPP folder of htdocs.
As there is not working XAMPP, I can't mount htdocs to access my working project folder.

Please suggest me to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Edit:

- macOS shows the error code `137`
- The files can be recovered by using the explanation [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=79609&sid=3ce5569a60c131c35226eb889c422fd3#p270491) (The mysql databases are in the folder `var/mysql/` next to the `htdocts/` folder)
- It seems like a fix is required to run XAMPP, but in the meantime, you can install XAMPP using homebrew and copy the recovered files

Edit 2:

An even easier fix can be found [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=79609&sid=3ce5569a60c131c35226eb889c422fd3#p270491). Look for the answer by Dennisv.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

I solved reinstalling XAMPP using Homebrew with command

`brew cask install xampp`

Unfortunately this way you would lose all your files, I haven't found a way to make the already installed version work.

Comment: backup your db and https-vhosts.conf!

Comment: if anyone getting cask error, try this 'brew install --cask xampp'