# Ampps not working after MacOS Big Sur install

Tags: installation, homebrew, ampps, macos-big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur, I can no longer open Ampps. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but the problem persists. When opening the application, it doesn't respond and you only get the Mac color wheel when hovering over the application. After waiting several minutes (approximately half an hour) the application still doesn't respond. Has anyone discovered a work around? I've noticed [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818894/xampp-is-not-working-on-mac-with-macos-big-sur) that found some workarounds for Xampp using brew cask install, and I tried the same for Ampps with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, I believe they haven't optimized Ampps for Big Sur.
I think they are aware of the Ampps not responding so my suggestion is to use Xampp while waiting for the optimized version of Ampps for Big Sur!

Comment: I have same issue, even using XAMPP i can not install intl ext.  have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP Users

1. Guys just uninstall the exiting XAMPP form the mac (you can delete manually or you can delete using https://freemacsoft.net/downloads/AppCleaner_3.6.zip)
2. Restart the system.
3. Open Terminal and paste the below command and Enter

```
brew install --cask xampp
```